# Make alt-tab sequential, not 'sticky'

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, application-switcher

I am running 20.10 with ubuntu-desktop.

Default alt-tab behaviour is "go back to the last program."

For a thought experiment let's say there are four programs open on my desktop.

Like duplicates that are no doubt going to be suggested (I've read them), I don't want the default behaviour. But I don't care about it being "smart" either. I want alt-tab to **cycle through my open programs without going back to the last one I visited.** In other words, one press will go to program 1, two presses to program 2; if I'm on program 2, one press will go to program 3, two to program 4, three to program 1. The desired behaviour is that it *never* goes "back."

Grouping is *not* a concern here. If I can get the focus to move sequentially, I don't care about grouping. I just care that every press of alt-tab gives me an option not tried before.

Impossible, you say? Well, the real goal is that I just want to alt-tab between my productivity applications. **If I can exclude a program or program(s) from alt-tab altogether (e.g., Slack), that is also a solution.**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete solution, but it may get you closer to your goal: this extension makes the app switcher choose only from the subset of apps on the *current* workspace. So you may be able to get a similar list of apps, and re-arrange them in the order you want.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4145/workspace-isolated-app-switcher/

Comment: I like it, unable to try right now but I will circle back.